# Two level toggle at my custom wordpress template

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

Hello I made a custom template in wordpress. I used WP Custom fields to make  new fields in admin panel. All works fine, but i want to add to my toggle  second level toggle. For example i have a first toggle - section when you click on it , it opens questions and then when you click on questions it open answers under each question.

Image how it looks right now: 
[image: toggle]

protocol_title_22 - Takes section name prom meta_post

protocol_title_2 - Takes Questions from meta_posts

What I want is to make multiple toggle menu, I have only 1 level toggle right now, but I want another toggle under Questions.

I tried to add some sub levels manually just copying and adding new lines but it just wont work correct.

```
              <div class="protocol">
                        <?php if( have_rows('protocol_2') ): ?>
                            <ul>
                                <?php while( have_rows('protocol_2') ):     the_row(); ?>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);" title="<?php the_sub_field('protocol_title_22'); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('protocol_title_22'); ?></a>                                      

                                        <?php if( have_rows('protocol_title_2') ): ?>
                                            <ul class="protocol-inner">                                 
                                                <?php while( have_rows(protocol_title_2) ): the_row();  ?>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a><?php the_sub_field(protocol_title_2); ?></a>                                                      

                                                    </li>
                                                <?php endwhile;  ?>
                                            </ul>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </li>
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
```

JS:

```
//protocols
$('.protocol .toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();      
    var $this = $(this);
    $('li a.toggle').removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass('active'); 
    if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
        $this.next().removeClass('show');
        $this.next().slideUp(300);
    } else {
        $this.parent().parent().find('li .protocol-inner').removeClass('show');
        $this.parent().parent().find('li .protocol-inner').slideUp(300);
        $this.next().toggleClass('show');
        $this.next().slideToggle(300);
    }
});
$('.protocol-inner li a').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }, 
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
);
//protocols
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I added what I want. But i told that already in text, that I want sub level toggle, I have right now a toggle Section when you click on it , it opens Questions. But I need the same option for questions too.

Comment: which plugin you are using for toggle? post your javascript code also

Comment: I added JavaScript. No plugin. I am not 100% because design is not done by me.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/Lcfud4hr/8/ check this

Answer (score 0):

I did this my self.  Just added under first toggle a new toggle:

```
<li>
    <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);" title="<?php the_sub_field('protocol_title_2'); ?>"><?php the_sub_field(protocol_title_2); ?></a>                                                      
    <ul class="protocol-inner"> 
        <li>
                <a ><?php the_sub_field(protocol_title_2); ?></a>                                                      
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```